# asp.net mvc configurable permission system

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, permissions, authorization

I am working on an asp.net mvc application which requires roles to have permissions associated with them and to have 'admins' able to alter what permissions roles have and create new permissions etc.

Basically, I am wondering if there is a pre-existing way to do this out there already which I have been unable to find.

EDIT:

This is pretty important information which I forgot to add:

> Ye, I should have been more clear, I need a 'role' that can read
>   CustomerA's data but not CustomerB's data. I was thinking having a
>   Role which you assign Permissions and then the permissions are what
>   allow you to do stuff, the role would never be checked.
>
> This also brings up another question: Can I get rid of asp.net
>   Identity roles and claims? I just want the AspNetUsers table then
>   build my own stuff.

Comment: not sure about the new MVC permissions system, but I always had to write my own 'admin pages' for the old role/membership providers

Comment: So you're saying that you actually do need object level permissions i.e. is it that this role can read customerA's data but not CustomerB's data OR is it that this role can read customer data, this role cant. Two entirely different animals. The former being a complete PITA but basically just NTFS style ACLs.

Comment: @rism Ye, I should have been more clear, I need a 'role' that can read CustomerA's data but not CustomerB's data. I was thinking having a Role which you assign Permissions and then the permissions are what allow you to do stuff, the role would never be checked.

This also brings up another question: Can I get rid of asp.net Identity roles and claims? I just want the AspNetUsers table then build my own stuff.